# Paginación en html

Tags: html, jquery, ionic, paginacion

Estoy obteniendo unos valores desde una lambda de AWS, esta trae información que la modelo a cierto gusto dependiendo de la tabla, todo funciona correcto. Pero hay veces que puede devolver hasta +30,000 elementos y es demasiada carga para la página, por lo que estoy haciendo la paginación de esta tabla.

Actualmente no conozco nada de jquery, sin embargo, me guie por un mini [tutorial simple](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) en el cual, lo único que no copio, es la tabla, ya que esta la tengo ya implementada y es dinámica.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<body>
      <table border="1" id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"> <!-- class="data-table" -->
        <thead>
     <tr >
       <th *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders" text-center><b>
         {{ header.replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ") }} <!-- headers es una variable en mi clase .ts -->
       </b></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <ng-container *ngIf="!searching">
     <tr *ngFor="let row of transactions">
       <td *ngFor="let value of row"> <!-- Tambien busco como hacer dinamica esta parte -->
          {{ value.Network }}
          {{ value.Err_Code }}
          {{ value.User }}
          {{ value["UUID_Transactions"] }}
          {{ value.DateDeposit }}
      </td>
     </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
   </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
  </script>
   </body>
```

Y el resultado, simplemente no genera los índices para moverme entre paginas, sin mencionar, que tampoco agrupa nada. Simplemente, no me funciona y toda la información que he encontrado, usan jquery o boostrap, pero ninguno me funciona como muestran que funciona.

P.D.
Estoy usando ionic, pero la tabla la tengo con html, espero no afecte mi pregunta

Comment: inspecciona el código html en el navegador y valida el id y que no este siendo usado por otro elemento. en la consola de javascript tambien puedes estar teniendo algún reporte de error valida estos dos puntos primero.

Comment: estas usando algún framework css??

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Como podría saber sii usan el mismo id? Esa la verdad no me la sabía... Y, no, no he usado ninguno de css

Comment: pues debes determinar cuantos elementos hay con el id example XD

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Aaaa ese , disculpá, no, ese ID estoy totalmente seguro que no lo utilizo en otro lado de mi página. Pensé que te referias al error en consola, que fuera por ese ID, pero no, ese id no se utiliza en otro lado (Hasta lo había cambiado a uno con mas sentido)

Comment: y que te sale en la consola de javascript algun error???

Comment: tambien valida esa estructura; por ejemplo esto: `<ng-container *ngIf="!searching"> `puede estar rompiendo el plugin.

Comment: Si estas usando `Ionic` puedes considerar `infinite scroll` o `lazy loading`. [Acá hay un minitutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-infinite-scroll-example/) en el que muestran cómo implementarlo.

Comment: @DjCrazy Esa no la conocia, le voy a echar un ojo

Answer (score 1):

Debes validar que no tengas los siguientes posibles errores:

1. Que tu `html` de la tabla este formado correctamente según la estructura de los ejemplos (esto es lo que da la mayor cantidad de problema un tag de mas o mal cerrado o mal ubicado y caput a todo el Javascript):

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

2. Que el tag `id` sea único no deben haber mas elementos con ese `id`.
3. Que al momento de inicializar la tabla el DOM este cargado. si la tabla es dinámica y se carga mediante `ajax`; tendrás que destruirla y cargarla en cada evento `ajax`.
4. Valida que estés implementando el UI correcto; en este ejemplo yo uso el CDN de la Pagina y la estructura de la del ejemplo básico sin estilos personalizados o CSS framework:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/css/buttons.dataTables.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

***Link de la Documentación:***

Datatables Sin CSS Framework (Clean):
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html

URL de la Descarga o CDN:
https://datatables.net/download/#dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.2/b-2.0.0/b-html5-2.0.0

***Update***

Según tus comentarios estas implementando IONIC el cual no esta soportado nativamente por el proveedor del plugin, seria bueno que te des una vuelta por estos tutoriales:

https://remotestack.io/ionic-angular-datatables-with-pagination-tutorial/
https://www.positronx.io/create-ionic-data-table-with-ngx-datatable/
https://devdactic.com/ionic-datatable-ngx-datatable/
https://ionicacademy.com/create-datatable-ionic/

Comment: Con ionic, la forma en que escribo en la tabla, es poniendo una variable en el archivo .ts que luego es leido en el html con `{{ miVariable }}`  no estoy usando `ajax`. El ejemplo que me das, lo ví y fue una guia muy buena, pero la parte del jquery (según creo es quien manda la orden para escribir la tabla, no? )es la que omití ya que la tabla se escribe cuando la lambda de aws me responde

Comment: no, Jquery en realidad busca el ID que le pasas como target `$('#Example')` toma el DOM Original de la tabla y lo pasa al método Datatable() quien es el que convierte en un Dataset enriquecido, si tu DOM original no cumple con la estructura del ejemplo te debe salir un error de javascript en la consola.

Comment: lo primero que tienes que hacer para implementar Datatables es imprimir ese codigo HTML y validar que es similar al del ejemplo...

Comment: tambien el numero de columnas debe ser el mismo que de head de la tabla... tienes una imagen del output html sin implementar el plugin datatable, ya validaste si hay algun error del javascript que se ve en la consola del navegador???

Comment: En la consola, no muestra ningun error... Le echaré el ojo a esos tutoriales que me mandaste, para mientras, gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: dale cualquier cosa me avisas, tambien estoy viendo que imprimes todas las variables dentro de un solo cuando cada td es una columna individual.

Comment: De eso se encarga el `*ngFor` que es la variable que tengo toda la información, como un diccionario. Por cada interacción, o por cada fila, se imprimen los valores... No se sii me entendes?

Comment: bueno no has agregado lo que te solicite asique no puedo avanzar mas en la ayuda... cuando actualices tu post con la informacion me avisas, saludos.

Comment: Sii, es que probando esos ngx me topé con una libreria que no es compatible, estoy buscando soluciones

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129828/discussion-between-alfa-rojo-and-francisco-nunez-todo-poderoso).

Comment: ok me dejas saber si necesitas mas ayuda pero todo apunta que el problema esta en otras librerías como lo indicas.